# Arquillian Suite Extension Error

Tags: jboss-arquillian, runtimeexception

I am having issue with integrating Arquillian Suite Extension.

I am following steps from this link 
https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension#easiest-way-to-move-to-suite

And I have added the required Deployment class and the run class.

Here is my error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke operation
    at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension$SuiteDeployer.executeInClassScope(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:210)
    at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension$SuiteDeployer.startup(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeSuite(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: See https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension/issues/16